# cURL не работает

Tags: php, curl, парсер

Пытаюсь сделать парсер, но не хочет работать, пишет

> Object Moved This object may be found here.

Гуглил, но решения не удалось найти. Что за метод защиты стоит, что запрещает парсить данные с данного сайта ?

```
$url = 'http://elibrary.ru/titles.asp';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $content;
```

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` не?

Comment: var_dump($content); //пишет false

Comment: а что говорит curl_error() ?

Comment: нечего, пустой екран

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Суть проблемы в следующем: целевой сайт выставляет cookie для идентификации пользователя и отдает код `302 Moved Temporarily` + заголовок `Location`. Это что-то вроде защиты от простеньких парсеров, не способных работать с cookie.

Если говорить о вашем коде, то опция `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` выставленная в `false` (или `0`), запрещает переходы по ссылкам из `Location`. Поэтому вы видите в ответе:

> Object moved

Выставление `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` в `true` (или `1`) не помогает в вашем случае потому, что curl по умолчанию все еще не работает с cookie. А чтобы работал, достаточно указать:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');
```

Пустая строка в качестве значения, указывает curl, что cookie должны быть использованы, однако без сохранения в файловую систему (см. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php).

Таким образом, работающий код может выглядеть так:

```
$url = 'http://elibrary.ru/titles.asp';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6');.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo($content);
```

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения, работает.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошее решение, долго не мог решить эту проблему.

Для некоторых сайтов обязательно не только cookie, но и строка user-agent:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6');`

после чего все заработало.